# How to download data via https via libcurl?

Tags: c++, libcurl

Build libcurl + openssl. I can not use https. I get an error: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate. Can i not use

```
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
```

and load https data?

Comment: On which platform? Is it a custom build of libcurl? On Linux libcurl is usually configured to use the system's CA certificate store. If building for other systems you will likely have to provide your own CA certificate in order to use OpenSSL. Or configure libcurl to use WinSSL/SecureTransport (for Windows and macOS respectively) instead of OpenSSL. https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html.

Comment: Disabling the certificate check should be avoided at all costs. It makes the transfer insecure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i downloaded cacert.pem (https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html), and paste this option.

```
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "cacert.pem" );
```